# A theorem and its proof in different places

Tags: numbering, positioning, theorems

I have a couple of theorems, proofs of which are quite boring and longish. I would like to place theorem formulations in a usual place and stack up the proofs at the end of the chapter. How to do this?

In particular I would like to:

- keep the original theorem numbering - the same number should be visible in both places, where the theorem is formulated originally, and at the end of the chapter,
- if possible, copy the original formulation of the theorem right before the proof is given without having to write the text twice

Comment: Do you care if there is a new proof environment generated that you use at a different location to where you define the theorem? Or is the intent that you specify the theorem & proof in one location of the chapter, and the proof printing is automatically postponed until the end of the chapter?

Comment: @Werner I don't really care about how the proof & theorem are generated. I actually think having them in one place would be easier to manage. I think you might have a point here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a MWE that demonstrates how the `answers` package can be used in this context. It preserves all of the numbering, as requested in your first bullet. Sadly I haven't managed to copy the original formulation of the theorem (your second bullet); perhaps someone else will be able to build from this though.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% open prooffile.tex
\Opensolutionfile{prooffile}
\Newassociation{myproof}{myProof}{prooffile}

% new theorem for demonstration
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{The theorems\ldots}
\begin{mytheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myproof}
This proves everything! 

\lipsum[2]
\end{myproof}
\end{mytheorem}

% close prooffile.tex
\Closesolutionfile{prooffile}

\clearpage
\section{The proofs!}
% can renew the environment to your liking
\renewenvironment{myProof}[1]{{\bfseries Proof of Theorem #1}}{}

\IfFileExists{prooffile.tex}{\input{prooffile.tex}}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Happily there is also `\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}`. I will test this today.

Comment: @julkiewicz yes indeed, a very useful option during construction!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the same theorem appear twice, with the same numbering, the `thm-restate` package does what you want.
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools
You essentially define a new command that produces the theorem, and choose one instance that chooses the number for it.