# command/enviroment that writes argument in predefined extra section

Tags: sectioning

I am working on a script and I would like to put some proofs in an extra section. But, for editing, I would like to place the proof right after the proposition.
So, I would like some kind of command that sends the input in a predefined section (For example: appends the input to the end of the section)

I have in mind something like this:

This code

```
\section{section}
Hello
\sendtoOtherSection{World}

\section{other section}
Nothing here
```

produces:

> **1 section**
>
> Hello
>
> **2 other section**
>
> Nothing here
>
> World

Like the title of this question says, I don't care if `\sendtoOtherSection` is a command or environment. It is not very important in which order the shifted text appears.

Comment: Will the "other section" always be after the "section"? (Because well, moving some data forward is much easier than backward.)

Comment: Have a look at [a-theorem-and-its-proof-in-different-places/45332#45332](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45324/a-theorem-and-its-proof-in-different-places/45332#45332) and see it helps- on first glance, I think it's a duplicate, if not, please say so

Comment: @cmhughes Thank you. This was quite helpful. So my question is a duplicate but I think the given answer is new (Peter Grill).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to just move the text forward, you could adapt the answer from [How keep a running list of strings and then process them one at a time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time) to keep building up these sections that need to appear later. Then when you want them to appear you just make a call to `\OtherSection`, and the code accumulated is typeset there:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\OtherSection{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sendtoOtherSection}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\OtherSection{{#1}\par\noindent}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\par\noindent
Hello. Hello.
\sendtoOtherSection{Is there anybody out there?}

\section{Section Two}
Goodbye Cruel World.
\sendtoOtherSection{I'm leaving you today.}

\section{Other Section}
\OtherSection
\end{document}
```